# How to configure rsyslogd to emit rfc5424 messages?

Tags: logs, syslog, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I want to configure my Linux machine using rsyslogd with the simplest yet standard way. I'll save all the logs to `/var/log/syslog` with rotation.

From my research it looks like the standard syslog format is defined by rfc5424, and I assume rsyslogd supports that format out of the box.

Yet I can't find any built-in template for rfc5424 in the rsyslogd documentation.

So how can I configure my rsyslogd for rfc5424 format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rsyslog` has a built-in template named `RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format` which is RFC5424 compatible.

Beats me why it does not define a template with more explicit name...

Comment: To quote the documentation:
  "... the format specified in IETF’s internet-draft ietf-syslog-protocol-23, which is very close to the actual syslog standard RFC5424 (we couldn’t update this template as things were in production for quite some time when RFC5424 was finally approved)."
i.e. Draft 23 of a proposed RFC, an RFC number is not issued until accepted, but an odd choice of name in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Avi said, to make RFC424 the default you can use:

For writing to files:

```
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

For sending to the network

```
$ActionForwardDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```